# primefaces component not updating the backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces layout component and having difficulty with a component in an embedded form:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" 
                    value="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.selectedAnswer}"
                    layout="custom">

<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option1" 
                    itemValue="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer1}"
                    rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question1}"/>

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option2" 
                    itemValue="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer2}"
                    rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question2}"/>

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option3" 
                    itemValue="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer3}"
                    rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question3}"/>

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option4" 
                    itemValue="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer4}"
                    rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question4}"/>

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option5" 
                    itemValue="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer5}"
                    rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question5}"/>

    <h:panelGrid columns="1">  
    <p:radioButton id="opt1"
        for="customRadio"
        itemIndex="0"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question1}"/>  
    <h:outputLabel for="opt1"
        value="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer1}"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question1}"/>
    <br/>
    <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" 
        itemIndex="1"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question2}"/>  
    <h:outputLabel for="opt2" 
        value="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer2}"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question2}"/>
    <br/>
    <p:radioButton id="opt3" 
        for="customRadio" 
        itemIndex="2"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question3}"/> 
    <h:outputLabel for="opt3" 
        value="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer3}"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question3}"/>
    <br/>
    <p:radioButton id="opt4" 
        for="customRadio" 
        itemIndex="3"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question4}"/>
    <h:outputLabel for="opt4" 
        value="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer4}"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question4}"/>
    <br/>
    <p:radioButton id="opt5" 
        for="customRadio" 
        itemIndex="4"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question5}"/> 
    <h:outputLabel for="opt5" 
        value="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.examentry.answer5}"
        rendered="#{exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.render_question5}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
```

The backing bean exams.examQuestions.currentQuestion.selectedAnswer is not updating when I select different items, how come? If I call an update on this component "customRadio" from the same form then the backing bean updates itself however I am unable to do this outside the form. Please help!

Comment: Was the problem where I've pointed ?

Comment: I needed to force an update after every <f:selectItem> to update the backing bean.

Comment: Yes, but you need to edit your code. You should terminate the `<p:selectOneRadio>` after the last `select item`. You are terminating it in the end of your code, take a look on link I've posted. Also if you want to update a component from another form you call the update like this `update=":formIdOfComponent:componentID"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what exactly do you want (cause I don't see any forms in your sample code), but I guess your problem is that you don't close the p:selectOneRadio after your last f:selectItem ...

Please take a closer look at primefaces showcase [selectOneRadio](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneRadio.jsf)

Also if you want to update a component from another form you call the update like this `update=":formIdOfComponent:componentID"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip about updating different forms as well. Super helpful.